How to Retrieve Template IDs from a Folder Containing Image or File Field Types
This is my PowerShell script, where templateFolderPath is a path of my template folder:
$templateFolderPath = "/sitecore/templates"
 
$templateIds = @()
 
$templateFolderItem = Get-Item -Path $templateFolderPath
 
if ($templateFolderItem -ne $null)
{
    $templates = Get-Item -Path $templateFolderPath -recurse | Where-Object { $_.Template.TemplateName -eq "Template" }
}

foreach ($template in $templates)
{
    $fields = $template.Fields

    foreach ($field in $fields)
    {
        if ($field.Type -eq "Image" -or $field.Type -eq "File")
        {
            $templateIds += $template.ID
            break 
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Template folder not found or path is incorrect."
}
 
if ($templateIds.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No templates with field type 'Image' found."
} else {
    Write-Host "Template IDs with field type 'Image':"
    $templateIds | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
}


So what is the issue you are facing?

i am not getting the template id's by using this script. Anything am i missing.

Below modified script works for me.

$templateFolderPath = "/sitecore/templates/testfoldername"
$templateIds = @()
$templateFolderItem = Get-Item -Path $templateFolderPath
if ($templateFolderItem -ne $null)
{
    $templates = Get-ChildItem -Path $templateFolderPath -Recurse
 
    foreach ($template in $templates)
    {
        if($template.Type -eq "Image")
        {$fields = $template.Name 
       Write-Host $template.Id
       Write-Host $template.Name}
       else{
       }
        foreach ($field in $fields)
        {
            #Write-Host $field.Type
             if ($field.Type -eq "Image" -or $field.Type -eq "File")
            {
                $templateIds += $template.ID
                break 
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Template folder not found or path is incorrect."
}
 
# Output the list of template IDs
if ($templateIds.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No templates with field type 'Image' found."
} else {
    Write-Host "Template IDs with field type 'Image':"
    $templateIds | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
}



Check below modified script this should work for you.
# Define an array to hold the template IDs
$templateIds = @()

# Check if the folder item exists
try {
    $templateFolderItem = Get-Item -Path $templateFolderPath -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    Write-Host "Template folder not found or path is incorrect."
    return
}

# Get all items recursively from the folder
$templates = Get-ChildItem -Path $templateFolderPath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Template.TemplateName -eq "Template" }

# Process each template
foreach ($template in $templates) {
    try {
        # Ensure the item is a valid template with fields
        if ($template -and $template.Fields) {
            $fields = $template.Fields

            # Check if any field type is 'Image' or 'File'
            foreach ($field in $fields) {
                if ($field.Type -eq "Image" -or $field.Type -eq "File") {
                    $templateIds += $template.ID
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error processing template at path: $($template.FullName)"
    }
}

# Output the results
if ($templateIds.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No templates with field type 'Image' or 'File' found."
} else {
    Write-Host "Template IDs with field type 'Image' or 'File':"
    $templateIds | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
}



Hope this helps!!!

By using the TemplateManager you can get the template, whereas the returned Template object exposes a method called GetFields(). Now, if you simply call the method, you will end up getting the fields on just the template. However, the GetFields() method has an overload, which takes in a boolean parameter called includeBaseFields, where you can explicitly say that you want to include all the base fields.
The solution is tested and working. Please check the same
# Path to the template folder
$templateFolderPath = "/sitecore/templates"

# List to store template IDs
$templateIds = @()

# Check if template folder exists
if (Test-Path $templateFolderPath) {
  # Get all templates under the specified path (recursively)
  $templates = Get-ChildItem -Path $templateFolderPath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq "Template" }

  # Loop through each template
  foreach ($template in $templates) {
    # Filter fields by type (Image or File) and get the first match
    $templateDetails = [Sitecore.Data.Managers.TemplateManager]::GetTemplate($template.ID, $template.Database)
    $allFields = $templateDetails.GetFields($true);
    $imageOrFileField = $allFields | Where-Object { $_.Type -eq "Image" -or $_.Type -eq "File" }

    # Check if any Image or File field found
    if ($imageOrFileField) {
      # Add the template ID to the list
      $templateIds += $template.ID
    }
  }

  # Check if any templates with Image/File fields found
  if ($templateIds.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No templates with field type 'Image' or 'File' found."
  } else {
    Write-Host "Template IDs with field type 'Image' or 'File':"
    $templateIds | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
  }
} else {
  Write-Host "Template folder not found or path is incorrect."
}

Hope this helps!!!

You need to replace the code as below, where you are trying to fetch all the templates under the template folder and checking whether the template has field type as Image or File.
$templateFolderPath = "/sitecore/templates"
$templateIds = @()
$templateFolderItem = Get-Item -Path $templateFolderPath

if ($templateFolderItem -ne $null)
{
    $templates = Get-ChildItem -Path $templateFolderPath -Recurse | Where-Object { 
    $_.TemplateName -eq "Template" }
}

foreach ($template in $templates)
{
    $allfields = ([Sitecore.Data.Items.TemplateItem]$template).Fields
    $customFields = $allfields | Where-Object { $_.Key -notlike '__**' }
    foreach ($field in $customFields)
    {
        if ($field.Type -eq "Image" -or $field.Type -eq "File")
        {
            $templateIds += $template.ID
            break 
        }
    }
}

if ($templateIds.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No templates with field type 'Image' found."
} else {
    Write-Host "Template IDs with field type 'Image':"
    $templateIds | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
}

This will return you all the templates containing field type as Image or File.
Moreover as an additional note, $template.Fields property on the template item will return all the fields on the template including base template fields whereas $template.OwnFields property will only return fields there on the template excluding base template fields.
Note: I have added the check above to filter out the standard fields.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issue.
